# How to set the height of a PageView.builder in Flutter based on screen size?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having an issue with the height of a `PageView.builder` in Flutter. I want to set the height based on the screen size. I tried using `MediaQuery` to set the height, but I'm still facing the issue.

I tried setting the height using `MediaQuery` like this:

```
final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
height: size.height / 2 * 1.2,
```

Here is the full code for my `PageView.builder` :

```
SizedBox(
    height: size.height / 2 * 1.2,
    child: PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
        });
      },
      itemCount: 3,
      physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 0, right: 20),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: Colors.accents[index].withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
            // height: size.height / 2,
            // width: size.width / 2 * 1.5,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Plan ${index + 1}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  Constants.height10,
                  const Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur itd ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Constants.height20,
                  ListView.separated(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Row(
                        children: const [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 3,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit '),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Constants.height10,
                  ),
                  const Divider(thickness: 2),
                  Row(
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        '\$199/',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 32,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          'month',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
```

But I'm still having the problem, as shown in this screenshot of two different sized screens:

[image]

I tried giving more space to avoid overflow, but when it comes to bigger screens, the PageView.builder becomes oversized and makes the UI look bad. I want to make the PageView.builder look like it does on iPhone screen on the given screenshot.

Can someone help me to properly set the height of the PageView.builder based on screen size in Flutter?.
thank you for your time

Comment: can you provide simplified minimal snippet by removing external widget/data. *when it comes to bigger screens, the PageView.builder becomes oversized* because you are using device height

Comment: @YeasinSheikh page view builder's code?

Comment: you can replace widgets like `SubscriptionHead`... so that others can simply run and reproduce the same error

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `LayoutBuilder` for responsive design, For your case , wrap the ListView with `Expanded` widget and follow

```dart
class PWF4 extends StatefulWidget {
  const PWF4({super.key});

  @override
  State<PWF4> createState() => _PWF4State();
}

class _PWF4State extends State<PWF4> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          final size = Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);

          return Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: size.height / 2 * 1.2,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  // controller: _pageController,
                  onPageChanged: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      // _currentIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  itemCount: 3,
                  physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 0, right: 20),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          color: Colors.accents[index].withOpacity(0.5),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Plan ${index + 1}',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                              // Constants.height10,
                              const Text(
                                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur itd ',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                              // Constants.height20,
                              SizedBox(height: 20),
                              Expanded(
                                child: ListView.separated(
                                  itemCount: 10,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return Row(
                                      children: const [
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 3,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                                        Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit '),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Divider(thickness: 2),
                              Row(
                                children: const [
                                  Text(
                                    '\$199/',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 32,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'month',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [adaptive-design](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive)

Comment: but it is taking full width of the screen

Comment: You can set the width on `SizedBox`

Answer (score -1):

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

Comment: No.  Just... no.  Yes, MediaQuery was how you did it in the web.  But this isn't the web.